# The return type is incompatible with FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)

Tags: android

I am following the tutorial here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html
I get this error in the "Problems": The return type is incompatible with FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(int)
Here is MyPageAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.loginandregistration;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter { 

private List<Fragment> fragments; 

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) { 

super(fm); 

this.fragments = fragments; 

} 


 @Override

 public Fragment getItem(int position) {
 return this.fragments.get(position);
 }

 @Override 

public int getCount() { 

return this.fragments.size(); 
  } 
   }
```

The error is on line 25:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
```

When I open up for the quick fix it gives me the one option to "Change return type of 'getItem(...)' to 'Fragment' but if I do that it gives me an error on the next line and is a continuous loop of those errors going back and forth.

Any help on fixing this really quick is apperciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this line

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

to this line

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

This error occurs because you are using `FragmentPagerAdapter` from the support package, thus it can only returns `Fragment` class from the support package.

Answer (score -1):

A `FragmentPagerAdapter` expects getItem to return a support Fragment.
You are returning a non-support Fragment.

Change your import from:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Answer (score -1):

change your import of Fragment to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

even if this doesnt work, change return type to

```
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
```